# Rspec ignore allow block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking, rspec-rails

I want to test a rails job which call an endpoint of hubspot API (GET /crm/v3/owners/{ownerId}) and update a record with infos of the request result.

The problem is that I use [this gem](https://github.com/HubSpot/hubspot-api-ruby) as an API wrapper and my `before` block seems like ignored because the result shows that the API call can't give me an owner object with this `owner_id` (the one given as parameter of `attributes` is obviously fake). A `before` block is supposed to override the "normal" response of the controller isn't it ?

I really don't know what I am doing wrong ..

For more context:

**My job code**

```rb
module Hubspots
  module Contracts
    class UpdateJob < BaseJob
      queue_as :high_priority

      def perform(attributes)
        contract = Contract.find_by(hubspot_sales_deal_id: attributes[:hubspot_sales_deal_id])
        return if contract.nil?

        deal_owner = client.crm.owners.owners_api.get_by_id(owner_id: attributes[:hubspot_tailor_deal_owner],
                                                            id_property: 'id', archived: false)

        attributes[:hubspot_tailor_deal_owner] = get_owner_name(deal_owner)

        contract.update!(attributes)
      end

      private

      def get_owner_name(hubspot_owner_object)
        "#{hubspot_owner_object.last_name.upcase} #{hubspot_owner_object.first_name.capitalize}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**My test code**

```rb
RSpec.describe Hubspots::Contracts::UpdateJob, type: :job do
  let!(:job) { described_class.new }
  let(:perform) { job.perform(attributes) }
  let!(:contract) { create(:contract, hubspot_sales_deal_id: 123) }
  let!(:attributes) do
    { hubspot_tailor_deal_id: 456, hubspot_tailor_deal_owner: 876, hubspot_sales_deal_id: 123 }
  end
  let!(:deal_owner_api) { Hubspot::Client.new(access_token: ENV['HUBSPOT_ACCESS_TOKEN']).crm.owners.owners_api }
  let!(:deal_owner_properties) { { last_name: 'Doe', first_name: 'John' } }

  before do
    allow(deal_owner_api).to receive(:get_by_id).and_return(deal_owner_properties)
  end

  describe '#perform' do
    it 'updates contract' do
      expect { perform }.to change { contract.reload.hubspot_tailor_deal_owner }.from(nil)
                                                                                .to('DOE John')
    end
  end
end
```

**Test result**
[image]

I try to rtfm on google but I didn't find the solution yet (I'm always bad for rtfm btw)

Comment: I think you need to mock the API call, what you are doing in your spec is actually creating an instance of the `Hubspot::Client` which is not going to work for you.

Comment: @Jax you're right but I don't find the right syntax to make it, because the `instace_double` method doesn't work for `Hubspot::Client.new(access_token: 'test').crm.owners.owners_api`
It returns me the same error than above

Comment: you just need to create a `double` I am not sure of your implementation of `client` probably in the base class.
I would do `let(:api_double) { Hubspot::Client }` 
`allow(Hubspot::Client).to receive(:new).and_return(api_double)`
`allow(api_double).to receive(<your methods>)` and return the value you want it to return

Comment: Hmm i see but it unfortunately doesn't work again ..
In the base job I implement `client` like that :
`def client
      Hubspot::Client.new(access_token: ENV['HUBSPOT_ACCESS_TOKEN'])
    end
`
So to access to the right part of the wrapper which have the `get_by_id` method I must write `Hubspot::Client.new(access_token: 'token').crm.owners.owners_api.get_by_id` and that's it that I can't mock with Rspec yet

Comment: it that case just mock the `client` method in the `Base` class to return what you want:
`let(:mock_client) { double(Base) }`
`allow(Base).to receive(:new).and_return(mock_client)`
`allow(mock_client).to return("whatever you want")`
Here is an article that may help `https://nebulab.com/blog/rspec-basic-using-test-doubles`

Comment: I made `let(:base) { Hubspots::BaseJob }` `allow(Hubspots::BaseJob).to receive(:new).and_return(base)` `allow(base.client.crm.owners.owners_api).to receive(:get_by_id).and_return(deal_owner_properties)` and the error message is : `NoMethodError: undefined method 'client' for Hubspots::BaseJob:Class`

Comment: you need to mock the `client` method not the api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my CTO finaly gave me the solution by using [the Webmock gem](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock)

The code snippet :

```rb
before do
    stub_request(:get, 'https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/owners/876?archived=false&idProperty=id')
      .with(headers: { 'Authorization' => "Bearer #{ENV['HUBSPOT_ACCESS_TOKEN']}" }).to_return(status: 200, body: {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe'
      }.to_json, headers: {})
  end

  describe '#perform' do
    it 'updates contract' do
      expect { perform }.to change { contract.reload.hubspot_tailor_deal_owner }.from(nil)
                                                                                .to('DOE John')
    end
  end
```